# Issue Downloading gribr package

Tags: r, grib, grib-api

I have been trying to download the R package gribr to work with grib data files in R but I have been getting some trouble with the download. Any assistance or direction on how to achieve this will be highly appreciated.

```
remotes::install_github("nawendt/gribr")
```

```
> Downloading GitHub repo nawendt/gribr@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsDzyVa\remotes81ac6bc768ec\nawendt-gribr-c1ea732/DESCRIPTION' (2.2s)
-  preparing 'gribr':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  running 'cleanup.win'
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (336ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'gribr_1.2.3.tar.gz'
   Warning: file 'gribr/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   Warning: file 'gribr/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   
* installing *source* package 'gribr' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

"C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/Users/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c grib_api_version.c -o grib_api_version.o
In file included from grib_api_version.c:4:
gribr.h:1:10: fatal error: eccodes.h: No such file or directory
 #include <eccodes.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/Users/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:222: grib_api_version.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gribr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/R-4.0.3/library/gribr
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to install the package.

Comment: @mhovd I have added the code used to download the data

Comment: Have you read the installation instructions on the main readme? https://github.com/nawendt/gribr. It seems you are using windows so have you installed the windows subsystem for linux or cygwin or condta?

Comment: And you will need other system packages as well. There is a section on the Github page entitled "Windows Install Options". But we cannot read the documentation for you.